# JavaFX: Get Node by row and column

Tags: java, javafx

Is there any way to get a specific Node from a gridPane if I know its location (row and column) or any other way to get a node from a gridPane?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20655024/3110608

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I don't see any direct API to get node by row column index, but you can use `getChildren` API from `Pane`, and `getRowIndex(Node child)` and `getColumnIndex(Node child)` from `GridPane`

```
//Gets the list of children of this Parent. 
public ObservableList<Node> getChildren() 
//Returns the child's column index constraint if set
public static java.lang.Integer getColumnIndex(Node child)
//Returns the child's row index constraint if set.
public static java.lang.Integer getRowIndex(Node child)
```

Here is the sample code to get the `Node` using row and column indices from the `GridPane`

```
public Node getNodeByRowColumnIndex (final int row, final int column, GridPane gridPane) {
    Node result = null;
    ObservableList<Node> childrens = gridPane.getChildren();

    for (Node node : childrens) {
        if(gridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row && gridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == column) {
            result = node;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Important Update:** `getRowIndex()` and `getColumnIndex()` are now static methods and should be changed to `GridPane.getRowIndex(node)` and `GridPane.getColumnIndex(node)`.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `java.lang.Integer` over the standard?

Comment: Please note that specifying `null` for the indices is also allowed; in this case the index is treated as `0`. In your case this results in a NPE though.

Comment: I think the methods `getRowIndex()` and `getColumnIndex()` only return a value if such a constraint has been set on the node i.e. there is no guarantee that these will return the column or row indices.

Comment: @Fabian does this mean that GridPane.getMargin(node) will always return null when the node is the first row in the grid pane?

Comment: @Bob I wasn't writing about `margin`, but `GidPane.getMargin(node)` will return `null`, if no margin was set for `node`, whether it's in the first row or not.

Comment: @Fabian sorry, I meant getRowIndex. I have a scenario where getRowIndex(node) returns null but I expect 0. If I put that same node in any other row, the method returns 1,2,3...

Comment: Make sure your constraints are set. Scenebuilder likes to treat 0 as not set and nulls the field. So manually set the constraints in the fxml file. e.g <Canvas GridPane.columnIndex=”0” GidPan.rowIndex=”0”>. Also since it's not guaranteed to return a non-null value from getRowIndex/getColumnIndex you should use an Integer object and check for null in the if statement. e.g.         if(null != nodeRow && null != nodeCol ...

Answer (score 2):

The above answer from @invariant is totally correct but for some people that do it that way, there may be performances issues, especially with GridPanes that contain many elements. *And also when working with loops (iterating over all the elements of a GridPane).*

What I suggest you is to initialize a static array of all your element/nodes contained within the grid pane. Then use this array to get the nodes you need.

i.e.

**1. have a double dimensional array :**

```
private Node[][] gridPaneArray = null;
```

**2. Call a method like so during the initialization of your view :**

```
    private void initializeGridPaneArray()
    {
       this.gridPaneArray = new Node[/*nbLines*/][/*nbColumns*/];
       for(Node node : this.mainPane.getChildren())
       {
          this.gridPaneArray[GridPane.getRowIndex(node)][GridPane.getColumnIndex(node)] = node;
       }
    }
```

**3. Get your node**

```
Node n = this.gridPaneArray[x][y]; // and cast it to any type you want/need
```