# JavaFX border pane Grid

Tags: java, javafx, grid, borderpane

I have a `BorderPane` and its center pane is `GridPane`.
The `GridPane` has 20x20 rectangle objects

```
 for (int rows = 0; rows < GRID_SIZE; ++rows) {
     for (int cols = 0; cols < GRID_SIZE; ++cols) {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(RECTANGLE_SIZE, RECTANGLE_SIZE);
            grid.add(r, rows, cols);
```

The `grid.add` method accepts:
 Node child - r, column and row index.

How could I access the grid using this index

my `BorderPane` is static for the class

```
  private static BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
```

So when I type bp.getCenter (the grid) I can't find any appropriate method for inserting column and row index, which would return my `Rectangle` object ?

Edit: 
solution [JavaFX: Get Node by row and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825935/javafx-get-node-by-row-and-column)

Comment: Why not just put the rectangles into an array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use static methods `GridPane.getColumnIndex(col)` and `GridPane.getRowIndex(n)`. Try this code:

```
public Optional<Rectangle> findByIndex(GridPane gridPane, int row, int col) {
    final Optional<Rectangle> rectangle = gridPane.getChildren().stream().map(n -> (Rectangle) n).filter(n -> GridPane.getColumnIndex(n) == col && GridPane.getRowIndex(n) == row).findFirst();
    return rectangle;
}
```

Comment: isn't this the same as iterating over the GridPane with for each loop ?

Comment: This can result in a NPE: `null` can be used instead of `Integer` `0`.