# How do I see if a specific CheckBox is selected within a GridPane?

Tags: java, javafx, checkbox, gridpane

I've created a 10x10 GridPane of CheckBoxes. I need to see whether a specific CheckBox is selected, but the GridPane is made up of nodes. So If I access a particular node using a function from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825935/javafx-get-node-by-row-and-column), I can't use *isSelected* because it is the wrong type.

I've tried modifying the function getNodeByRowColumnIndex or forcing the type to be CheckBox but I'm not sure how.

```java
@FXML
private GridPane Grid;

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            this.Grid.add(new CheckBox(), x, y);
            //Problem here
            boolean bln = getNodeByRowColumnIndex(y,x,this.Grid).isSelected();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getNodeByRowColumnIndex` returns a `Node`. You need to cast it to `CheckBox` :

```
Node node = getNodeByRowColumnIndex(y,x,this.Grid);
    if(node instanceof CheckBox){
          boolean bln = ((CheckBox)node).isSelected();
          //todo use bln
}
```

Side note 1 : It is not clear why you want to check `isSelected` for a `CheckBox` you just added. 
Side note 2: as per [java naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/) use `GridPane grid`.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the source code below.

@FXML
private GridPane imageGridPane;

imageGridPane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler() {

```
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
    Node clickedNode = (Node) e.getTarget();
    if (clickedNode != imageGridPane) {
        Node parent = clickedNode.getParent();
        while (parent != imageGridPane) {
            clickedNode = parent;
            parent = clickedNode.getParent();
        }
        Integer colIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(clickedNode);
        Integer rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(clickedNode);
        System.out.println("Mouse clicked cell: " + colIndex + " And: " + rowIndex);
        CheckBox itemNoCheckBox = (CheckBox) ((BorderPane) clickedNode).getTop();
        System.out.println("itemNo: " + itemNoCheckBox.getText());
        if (itemNoCheckBox.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("Selected");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Deselected");
        }
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).