# How does this code for finding the location of a node in a GridPane cause a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a week view for a simple scheduling application in JavaFX. The view consists of a 8x49 `GridPane`. The first column shows times and the first row shows the days of the week, similar to the week view on Google calendar and other calendar software. When the user changes the date, I want to clear the grid except for the first column and first row. I borrowed a method from an answer in another SO question. It works perfectly in my day view panel (exactly the same code except is a 2x49 grid instead) but throws a `NullPointerException` in my week view panel.

I added two `System.out.println()` statements to see if anything is actually `null`. As far as I can tell, nothing is. I removed `GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row` to see if that might be the issue and the exception no longer happened, leading me to believe this statement is somehow causing the exception.

Here is the offending method, borrowed from [Shreyas Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655024/javafx-gridpane-retrieve-specific-cell-content). I added line numbers for correlation with the stack trace below:

```java
130: private Node getNodeFromGridPane(GridPane gridPane, int col, int row) {
131:     System.out.println("Gridpane: " + gridPane.getChildren().toString());
132:     for (Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
133:         System.out.println("Node: " + node.toString());
134:         if (GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == col && GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row) {
135:             return node;
136:         }
137:     }
138:     return null;
139: }
```

Here is the method that calls `getNodeFromGridPane`:

```java
    private void clearAppointmentsColumn(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 49; i++){
            Node node = getNodeFromGridPane(grid, 1, i+1);
            if(node != null){
                grid.getChildren().remove(node);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the output of the `System.out.println()` statements and the relevant part of the stack trace:

```
Gridpane: [Label@4b093381[styleClass=label]'Monday', Label@44994e49[styleClass=label]'Tuesday', Label@6f3b59bb[styleClass=label]'Saturday', Label@61dea913[styleClass=label]'Sunday', Label@2f46425[styleClass=label]'Thursday', Label@37370341[styleClass=label]'Wednesday', HBox@3b64a2ab, HBox@3031ce6e, HBox@2e8b5a86, HBox@7d2748fa, HBox@1f40aa1b, HBox@46404c48, HBox@6b829580, HBox@131fffd9, HBox@5a3e3d63, HBox@2f889183, HBox@5d56c9f0, HBox@5f2d13f2, HBox@37bf973, HBox@145f557e, HBox@6db9d36a, HBox@738a8500, HBox@49655482, HBox@75505497, HBox@5b1abd8b, HBox@557f1cad, HBox@223c3dd1, HBox@4d317b8e, HBox@3b093ec, HBox@1183928c]
Node: Label@4b093381[styleClass=label]'Monday'
Node: Label@44994e49[styleClass=label]'Tuesday'
Node: Label@6f3b59bb[styleClass=label]'Saturday'
Node: Label@61dea913[styleClass=label]'Sunday'
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at appointmentcalendar.WeekViewController.getNodeFromGridPane(WeekViewController.java:134)
    at appointmentcalendar.WeekViewController.clearAppointmentsColumn(WeekViewController.java:108)
    at appointmentcalendar.WeekViewController.setDate(WeekViewController.java:74)
    at appointmentcalendar.MainWindowController.refreshWeekView(MainWindowController.java:467)
    at appointmentcalendar.MainWindowController.datePicked(MainWindowController.java:455)
    at appointmentcalendar.AppointmentCalendar.switchToMainWindow(AppointmentCalendar.java:90)
    at appointmentcalendar.LoginFormController.loginClicked(LoginFormController.java:71)
    ... 75 more
```

Line 134 is the `if` statement in `getNodeFromGridPane`.

As I said, this method works perfectly in my `DayViewController` which is literally the same code (`WeekViewController.java` and `WeekView.fxml` are a direct copy and paste duplicates, the only difference thus far is the number of columns in the `GridPane`). When run on the `WeekViewController`, the method processes exactly 4 nodes before throwing the exception. They are the same 4 nodes every time. I tried removing the 5th node from the `GridPane` and the results did not change. The window displays properly and everything else in the application functions. I cannot see any reason this would throw a `NullPointerException`. Are you guys able to spot something I am missing?

**UPDATE**
The issue is, in fact, that the `getRowIndex()` method is returning `null` for some of the nodes, as pointed out by Bastida. Upon revising the method to the following code, the issue disappeared:

```java
    private Node getNodeFromGridPane(GridPane gridPane, int col, int row) {
        System.out.println("Gridpane: " + gridPane.getChildren().toString());
        for (Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println("Node: " + node.toString());
            Integer c = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
            c = c == null ? 0 : c;
            Integer r = GridPane.getRowIndex(node);
            r = r == null ? 0 : r;
            if (c == col && r  == row) {
                return node;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: So either `GridPane.getColumnIndex(node)` or `GridPane.getRowIndex(node)` returns `null`. Have you tried printing those out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX: Get Node by row and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825935/javafx-get-node-by-row-and-column)

Comment: Be sure to read all the comments for the duplicate question's answer, as it specifically addresses the NPE issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is comparing int with a Integer(It can handle posible null value).

In my opinion you can do this to solve your problem:

Verify that `GridPane.getColumnIndex(node)` and `GridPane.getRowIndex(node)` are both another value than null like this:

```
private Node getNodeFromGridPane(GridPane gridPane, int col, int row) {
System.out.println("Gridpane: " + gridPane.getChildren().toString());
for (Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
    System.out.println("Node: " + node.toString());
    if (GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) != null && GridPane.getRowIndex(node) != null &&
        GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == col && GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row) {
        return node;
    }
}
return null;}
```

Hope this helped you :)

Comment: I'd recommend rewriting the check a bit to avoid calling the getters multiple times and properly treat the default value: `Integer cIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node); if (cIndex == null ? col == 0 : cIndex == col) { Integer rIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(node); if (rIndex == null ? row == 0 : row == rIndex) { return node; }}`

Comment: They will never be null. The reason for the NPE is the return null at the bottom. The problem is the the comparison of int to Integer this can be solved by changing the parameter to Integer

Comment: The check is unnecessary